# Quickblox messages with russian language

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I'm using [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/) as a clock backend for my chap-application. But now I've met a problem that when user write message on Russsian language, it contains only "?????" symbols instead of real message. Looks like problem is with encoding.

Any ideas or alternative for mobile chat backend platform?

Comment: Did you try to add the UTF format for string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used hardcoded string in my project and Android Studio used windows-1252 encoding, so my String was broken by default.